# How to figure out the "No Most Popular" game genre

Tags: game-tycoon-1.5

I'm playing [Game Tycoon 1.5](http://store.steampowered.com/app/273770/Game_Tycoon_15/) and there is a contract that ask you to create a "No Most Popular" game genre

[image: No most popular genre]

I can't figure out how to discover that genre. There must be a place that shows a ranking or something. Where is it?